# Length and details of a personal statement in postdoc positions?

Tags: application, postdocs, statement-of-purpose, facilities-services

I am trying to apply for postdoc position in the UK. During the application process, I found that the personal statement is a **required** file and cv is an additional document. So, the personal statement is really important and I've never wrote one. There are those who say a personal statement shouldn't be longer than a paragraph with a few lines, and some people say it can longer if it's for a job in university.

When I applied to other positions, I wrote research statements and supporting statements but I think the structure of this one is different. So, how long is a personal statement and what questions should my personal statement answer? For instance, can I talk about my past research? research issues in the project I will be working on?

**PS:** I am looking for information that are related to postdoc positions. I believe the blogs I read talk about general jobs, grants, etc. But I didn't find a lot of information about research positions.

Comment: Is this just a different name for an SoP (Statement of Purpose)?

Comment: Honestly I don't know. But a first Google search said this "So, the difference between these two types of essays is that the Personal Statement focuses on your individual background and your own special reasons for pursuing the degree while the Statement of Purpose spotlights your career goals and preparedness for this degree program."

Comment: If you have a way to ask, it would be worth doing.

Answer (score 1):

If they only ask for personal statement and CV then you need to find a way to squeeze in the personal statement basically everything. I would start by introducing what your studies were so far and what kind of results you got. Highlight the significance of your research and what are the next steps. Then write about collaborations you had and how you expanded your scientific network. Conclude by saying what your future plans in terms of career are. It is not an easy thing to write so I would start just writing down everything you can think of and then you start ordering things. With this kind of stuff the easiest way to tackle it is to just start writing. Ultimately it is a personal statement so you need to add some personal touch. Let people that knows you well read it and ask them their opinion even if they are not scientist. Good luck with your application!

Comment: Actually the CV alone should detail the past. The SoP looks to the future. Don't waste words on "what you did". Speak about what you intend to do in future.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But wouldn't that be a bit lengthy?

Comment: I forgot to mention the length. I would keep it maximum one page length which with nice formatting it is not much. By what you did in the past I mean just the first two sentences. It is not detailed of course but the first two sentences should show your passion for science and your passion for what to you have studied/done so far and the reason why you want to go for that specific postdoc position. Plus why is the perfect position and why it is perfect now and not next year for example. I know it's a lot of stuff, but once you have written down everything it is much easier to refine after.

Comment: Bare in mind that there is not a right answer or a right way to write this kind of stuff, it is just my opinion.